# How does Django find if i a user is authenticated?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a SPA that uses Django on the backend for authentication, and i'm using Session Authentication.

In order to check if a user is authenticated, the SPA sends Django a standard request to an endpoint that will simply return `request.user.is_authenticated`. This works because the sessionid cookie is always sent from the client to the Django app.

In another part of the SPA app, for some reason the cookie is not being sent with the request, so Django always returns `False` even when the user is logged in. The solution i found is to send the sessionid cookie in the POST request body, but this will still return `False`.

Since that didn't work either, i had this idea: if the sessionid cookie is not in the cookies but it is in the request's body, set the cookie manually from the view:

```
def checkAuth(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session_cookies = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        request.COOKIES['sessionid'] = session_cookies['sessionid']
        request.COOKIES['csrftoken'] = session_cookies['csrftoken']
        print(request.COOKIES)

    response = {'state': str(request.user.is_authenticated), 'username': str(request.user)}
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

Here i see the cookies being set in the view:

```
{'sessionid': 'somecookie', 'csrftoken': 'sometoken'}
```

But `request.user.is_authenticated` still returns `False`. Why is that? Is there any way i can solve this?

Comment: The `request.user` is added by the `AuthenticationMiddleware`, so that is *before* control is passed to the view.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. So basically i would need to edit the AuthMiddleware